# Erro no react-native: não se comunica com AVD ou devices

Tags: javascript, android, react, react-native

Mim deparei com o seguinte erro: meu app não consegui se comunicar com o AVD android e nem com meu Device.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Ambos estão conectados e funcionando...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

O erro foi corrigido com a correção da variável de ambiente JAVA_HOME.
Tanto para usuário como para sessão. Basta criar e react-native encontrar se comunica com o emulador